# AppStore Connect removal of Add button on build

Tags: app-store-connect

[image]

Recently I needed to update one of my apps on Appstore connect. I did the build for it on Codemagic as I do not intend on wasting money on Apples products. Codemagic sent my build to TestFlight as per the norm, then I went to create an update version and found that the build has no longer got the add button?? I am not sure if this is an error or if they are now forcing Devs to use their products to move TestFlight builds to production? If anyone knows please advise!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption
 to info.plist is what was stopping me from seeing the add button.